# Gitlab update breaking jest tests

Tags: docker, unit-testing, jestjs, gitlab

I recently updated my gitlab instance (`gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.10.0-ce.0` -> `gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.10.6-ce.0`) and it seems to have broken jest and/or coverage reports for my nodejs applications. This is what the job looks like

```yaml
test:
  stage: check
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/
  image: node:16
  needs:
    - job: init
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - npm run test:ci
  cache:
    paths:
      - coverage/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
    when: always
    reports:   
      junit:
        - junit.xml               
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
```

and my `package.json`

```json
"test:ci": "jest --config=config/jest.config.ts --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --ci",
```

Logs from gitlab job

```bash
Running with gitlab-runner 16.1.0 (865283c5)
  on runner with ubuntu base-image qP_Zsz4P, system ID: s_aa54348ff65e
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:02
Using Docker executor with image node:16 ...
Pulling docker image node:16 ...
Using docker image sha256:81c6e5ef93fcc0f603ac62cb5b8fbda4575af20f5003d5da1d229b54d02d97c4 for node:16 with digest node@sha256:466d0a05ecb1e5b9890960592311fa10c2bc6012fc27dbfdcc74abf10fc324fc ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-qpzsz4p-project-36-concurrent-0 via cfc...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/gitlab/campus-freecity/morgana/ui-service/.git/
Checking out e7530d1c as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Removing node_modules/
Removing package-lock.json
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:03
Checking cache for default-protected...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:12
Using docker image sha256:81c6e5ef93fcc0f603ac62cb5b8fbda4575af20f5003d5da1d229b54d02d97c4 for node:16 with digest node@sha256:466d0a05ecb1e5b9890960592311fa10c2bc6012fc27dbfdcc74abf10fc324fc ...
$ npm run test:ci
> ui-service@1.3.0 test:ci
> jest --config=config/jest.config.ts --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --ci
PASS tests/unit/element.unit.test.ts
  Elements-Service & Controller tests
    ✓ "getAllElements" should return an array (5 ms)
    ✓ "getElementById" should return 200 and elementId (1 ms)
    ✓ "getElementById" should return 204 (1 ms)
    ✓ "createElement" should return 200 (2 ms)
    ✓ "updateElementById" should return updated interface (1 ms)
    ✓ "deleteElementById" should return 200 (8 ms)
    ✓ "deleteElementById" should return 204 (1 ms)
    ✓ "getElementsByInterfaceId" should return an array & 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "getElementsByInterfaceId" should return 204 (1 ms)
    ✓ "getElementByInterfaceId" should return 200 and elementId (2 ms)
    ✓ "getElementByInterfaceId" should return 204 (1 ms)
    ✓ "deleteElementByInterfaceId" should return 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "deleteElementByInterfaceId" should return 204 (1 ms)
    ✓ "addElementByInterfaceId" should return 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "updateElementByInterfaceId" should return 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "getAllElements" should return an array (1 ms)
    ✓ "getElementById" should return 200 and elementId (1 ms)
    ✓ "createElement" should return 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "updateElementById" should return updated interface
    ✓ "deleteElementById" should return 200
    ✓ "getElementsByInterfaceId" should return an array & 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "getElementByInterfaceId" should return 200 and elementId (1 ms)
    ✓ "deleteElementByInterfaceId" should return 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "addElementByInterfaceId" should return 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "updateElementByInterfaceId" should return 200
    ✓ Should load 9 routes
PASS tests/unit/interface.unit.test.ts
  Interface-Service & Controller tests
    ✓ "getAllInterfaces" should return an array (4 ms)
    ✓ "getInterfaceById" should return 200 and interfaceId (2 ms)
    ✓ "getInterfaceById" should return 204 (16 ms)
    ✓ "deleteInterfaceById" should return 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "deleteInterfaceById" should return 204 (1 ms)
    ✓ "createInterface" should return 200 (1 ms)
    ✓ "updateInterfaceById" should return updated interface (1 ms)
    ✓ "getAllInterfaces" should return error
    ✓ "getInterfaceById" should return error (1 ms)
    ✓ "deleteInterfaceById" should return error (1 ms)
    ✓ "createInterface" should return error
    ✓ "updateInterfaceById" should return error (1 ms)
    ✓ Should load 6 routes (1 ms)
PASS tests/unit/validator.unit.test.ts
  Validator tests
    ✓ Expect schemas to have 7 routes (3 ms)
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: coverage/: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/gitlab/campus-freecity/morgana/ui-service) 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Uploading artifacts...
junit.xml: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=1008 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_xSG7a
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/gitlab/campus-freecity/morgana/ui-service) 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

All tests pass (I checked locally as well) but somehow it states that the job failed and therefore does not upload anything. I'm not sure whats happening especially since I've been using the same job for over half a year now. Anyone having similar issues and knows a solution? Nothing worked

EDIT: I've done a few more tests and the problem seems to be coverage. I tried testing without `--coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --ci` and then the tests succeed but the job is obviously still crashing because now coverage information is missing. Can anyone help?